# Does the phrase "to cry out loud" mean "to scream" or to "break down in tears"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could someone please clarify the contextual meaning of the lyric "I'll cry out loud" in ABBA's song "That's Me"?

> If you hurt my feelings **I'll cry out loud**

Does this mean A) that she'll scream, or B) that she'll break down in tears?

Comment: To cry out cam be a shout of victory being ecstatic

Comment: The phrase "For crying out loud" is a euphemism for "for Christ's sake." See [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/for-crying-out-loud). So "I'll cry out loud" may mean to exclaim in anger or exasperation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To cry out loud* would, in normal conversational English, mean *to scream*. The act of breaking down in tears is not necessarily accompanied by audible sobbing. But you have to remember that song lyrics can mean completely different things to different listeners, and the lyricist or poet very often deliberately employs vagueness to avoid a single unambiguous interpretation of the words.

I think either interpretation is valid in this case.